# Cannot access runtime parameter when using kedro run --params

Tags: python, parameters, command-line-interface, runtime, kedro

Kedro fails to resolve for runtime parameters passed via the CLI with the following error :

```
InterpolationResolutionError(
omegaconf.errors.InterpolationResolutionError: Runtime parameter 'start_date' not found and no default value provided.
```

I am trying to run my pipeline with runtime parameters via the CLI as follows :

```
kedro run --params=start_date='2023-10-10',end_date='2023-10-11'
```

or

```
kedro run --params start_date='2023-10-10',end_date='2023-10-11'
```

I expected to be able to use these parameters in my pipeline but I get :

```
InterpolationResolutionError(
omegaconf.errors.InterpolationResolutionError: Runtime parameter 'start_date' not found and no default value provided.
    full_key: start_date
    object_type=dict
```

Following what it advised [in the official doc](https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/configuration/advanced_configuration.html#how-to-override-configuration-with-runtime-parameters-with-the-omegaconfigloader), I wrote my parameters.yml file is as follows :

```
start_date: "${runtime_params:start_date}"
end_date: "${runtime_params:end_date}"
```

Everything works as expected when I explicitly specify a start_date and end_date in the parameters.yml file :

```
start_date: '2023-10-10'
end_date: '2023-10-11'
```

I am using kedro 0.19.1 and python3.10.12.